# I want to make a tkinter timer class which can be opened as many times you want and also run at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to make a Timer in tkinter which can be opened as many Times you want. The Problem is that even though you can open the Timer as many Times you want only one Timer can run at the same time.
Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?
I just started programming with tkinter.
I don't know if running multiple programs at the same time is even possible with tkinter.
Because the Buttons work fine it's just the Countdown which only works in one window at a time.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class MyFirstGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        master.title("Timer")

        self.Canvas_Timer_x = 460
        self.Canvas_Timer_y = 460
        self.minutes_default = 15
        self.seconds_default = 0



        self.temp = 0
        self.Hold = False
        self.tempstart = 1
        self.tempcurrent = 0
        self.Wiget_x = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.3333))
        self.Wiget_y = int((self.Canvas_Timer_y * 0.1666))

        self.Circle_Timer_x = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.2667))
        self.Circle_Timer_y = int((self.Canvas_Timer_y * 0.5))
        self.Canvas_hight = int((self.Canvas_Timer_y * 0.43))
        self.Canvas_wight = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.43))

        self.Circle_Diameter = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.2))
        self.Circle_Boarder = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.167))

        self.Entry_x = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.3333))
        self.Entry_y = int((self.Canvas_Timer_y * 0.0555))

        self.minute = tk.StringVar()
        self.second = tk.StringVar()

        self.minute.set(str(self.minutes_default))
        self.second.set(str(self.seconds_default))

        self.minuteEntry = tk.Entry(master, width=3, font=("Arial", 18, ""),
                                    textvariable=self.minute)
        self.minuteEntry.place(x=self.Entry_x, y=self.Entry_y)

        self.secondEntry = tk.Entry(master, width=3, font=("Arial", 18, ""),
                                    textvariable=self.second)
        self.secondEntry.place(x=(self.Entry_x + 50), y=self.Entry_y)

        self.btn = tk.Button(master, text='Countdown', bd='5',
                             command=self.Countdown)
        self.btn.place(x=self.Wiget_x, y=self.Wiget_y)
        self.btn_reset = tk.Button(master, text='RESET', bd='5',
                                   command=self.reset)
        self.btn_reset.place(x=self.Wiget_x, y=(self.Wiget_y + 30))
        self.btn_stop = tk.Button(master, text='STOP', bd='5',
                                  command=self.stop)
        self.btn_stop.place(x=self.Wiget_x, y=(self.Wiget_y + 60))
        self.btn_restart = tk.Button(master, text='Restart', bd='5',
                                     command=self.restart)
        self.btn_restart.place(x=self.Wiget_x, y=(self.Wiget_y + 90))

        

    def Countdown(self):

        try:
            self.temp = int(self.minute.get()) * 60 + int(self.second.get())
            self.tempstart = self.temp

        except:
            print("Please input the right value")
        while (self.temp > -1) and (self.Hold == False):
            mins = str(self.minutes_default)
            mins, secs = divmod(self.temp, 60)
            self.minute.set("{0:2d}".format(mins))
            self.second.set("{0:2d}".format(secs))
            self.after(1000)
            self.update()
            if self.temp == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time's up ")
            self.temp -= 1
            self.tempcurrent = self.temp

    def reset(self):

        self.minute.set(str(self.minutes_default))
        self.second.set("00")
        self.Hold = False
        self.Countdown()
        return

    def stop(self):
        self.Hold = True
        self.Countdown()
        return

    def restart(self):

        self.update()
        self.Hold = False
        self.Countdown()
        return



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
    my_gui2 = MyFirstGUI(tk.Toplevel(root))
    my_gui3 = MyFirstGUI(tk.Toplevel(root))

    

    while True:
        my_gui.update()
        my_gui2.update()
        my_gui2.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using tkinter with infinite (or very long) while loops, these will prevent other parts of the program from updating. When you click Countdown in one instance, the while loop inside the `Countdown` function will continue to hold control of the program until it finishes.

You should be using tkinter's `after` method to schedule the timers to update periodically after you have pressed the Countdown button. Your code should also have a `mainloop` call. Personally I also try to avoid using the tkinter `update` method if I can at all avoid it.

The code below attempts to fix some of the problems by using `after`, having separate functions to start, set the number on the display and update the timer.

An issue left for the OP to fix is that the if you click the Countdown button more than once, the countdown will get progressively quicker.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class MyFirstGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        master.title("Timer")

        self.Canvas_Timer_x = 460
        self.Canvas_Timer_y = 460
        self.minutes_default = 15
        self.seconds_default = 0



        self.temp = 0
        self.Hold = False
        self.tempstart = 1
        self.tempcurrent = 0
        self.Wiget_x = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.3333))
        self.Wiget_y = int((self.Canvas_Timer_y * 0.1666))

        self.Circle_Timer_x = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.2667))
        self.Circle_Timer_y = int((self.Canvas_Timer_y * 0.5))
        self.Canvas_hight = int((self.Canvas_Timer_y * 0.43))
        self.Canvas_wight = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.43))

        self.Circle_Diameter = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.2))
        self.Circle_Boarder = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.167))

        self.Entry_x = int((self.Canvas_Timer_x * 0.3333))
        self.Entry_y = int((self.Canvas_Timer_y * 0.0555))

        self.minute = tk.StringVar()
        self.second = tk.StringVar()

        self.minute.set(str(self.minutes_default))
        self.second.set(str(self.seconds_default))

        self.minuteEntry = tk.Entry(master, width=3, font=("Arial", 18, ""),
                                    textvariable=self.minute)
        self.minuteEntry.place(x=self.Entry_x, y=self.Entry_y)

        self.secondEntry = tk.Entry(master, width=3, font=("Arial", 18, ""),
                                    textvariable=self.second)
        self.secondEntry.place(x=(self.Entry_x + 50), y=self.Entry_y)

        self.btn = tk.Button(master, text='Countdown', bd='5',
                             command=self.Countdown)
        self.btn.place(x=self.Wiget_x, y=self.Wiget_y)
        self.btn_reset = tk.Button(master, text='RESET', bd='5',
                                   command=self.reset)
        self.btn_reset.place(x=self.Wiget_x, y=(self.Wiget_y + 30))
        self.btn_stop = tk.Button(master, text='STOP', bd='5',
                                  command=self.stop)
        self.btn_stop.place(x=self.Wiget_x, y=(self.Wiget_y + 60))
        self.btn_restart = tk.Button(master, text='Restart', bd='5',
                                     command=self.restart)
        self.btn_restart.place(x=self.Wiget_x, y=(self.Wiget_y + 90))

        self.timer = None

    def Countdown(self):

        try:
            self.temp = int(self.minute.get()) * 60 + int(self.second.get())
            self.tempstart = self.temp

        except:
            print("Please input the right value")

        self.set_display()

        if not self.timer:
            self.timer = self.after(1000,self.update)

    def set_display(self):
        mins = str(self.minutes_default)
        mins, secs = divmod(self.temp, 60)
        self.minute.set("{0:2d}".format(mins))
        self.second.set("{0:2d}".format(secs))

    def update(self):
        if (self.temp > -1) and (self.Hold == False):
            self.set_display()
            
            if self.temp == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time's up ")
            self.temp -= 1
            self.tempcurrent = self.temp
        self.timer = self.after(1000,self.update)

    def reset(self):

        self.minute.set(str(self.minutes_default))
        self.second.set("00")
        self.Hold = False
        self.Countdown()
        return

    def stop(self):
        self.Hold = True
        self.Countdown()
        return

    def restart(self):

        self.update()
        self.Hold = False
        self.Countdown()
        return



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
    my_gui2 = MyFirstGUI(tk.Toplevel(root))
    my_gui3 = MyFirstGUI(tk.Toplevel(root))

    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to upgrade my Timer with more functions and I will try to use the tips you gave me.